# product validation failed error while using post api

Tags: node.js, express

I have created post and get request for product in node express. get request API is working fine but post request through an error:

models.js file

```
const mongoose=require("mongoose")

const produdctSchema=new  mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required:true,
        trim: true,
      },
    description:{
        type:String,
        required:[true, "please enter product description"]
    },
    price:{
        type:Number,
        required:[true, "please enter product price"]
    },
    rating:{
        type:Number,
        default:0
    },

    category:{
       type:String,
        required:true
    },
    stock:{
        type:Number,
        requird:true,
        default:1
    },
    numOfReview:{
        type:Number,
        default:0,

    },
   
   createdAt:{
     type:Date,
     default:Date.now()
 }
})

module.exports=mongoose.model("product",produdctSchema)
```

routes.js file

```
const express = require("express");
const {allproductController,createProductController}=require("../controllers/productControllers.js")

const router=express.Router();

router.route("/product/new").post(createProductController);
router.route("/products").get(allproductController)

module.exports= router
```

controllers.js file

```
const Product= require("../models/productModel.js")

exports.createProductController=async (req,res,next)=>{
    try {
   
        const product = await Product.create(req.body);
        res.status(201).json({
            success:true,
            product
        })
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({
            success:false,
            message:error.message
        })
    }
};

exports.allproductController=async(req,res)=>{
    try {
        const products=await Product.find();
        res.status(200).json({message:"success",data:products})
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({message:"error"})
    }

}
```

get API is working but when post API call it through an catch error in post man
"product validation failed: category: Path `category` is required., price: please enter product price, description: please enter product description, name: Path `name` is required."
}

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you destructure the req.body object into their individual fields;

```
const {name, description, price, rating, category, stock, numOfReviews, createdAt } = 
req.body;

try {
    const product = await Product.create({
          name,              
          description,       
          price,             
          rating,            
          category,
          stock,
          numOfReviews,
          createdAt
    });
    res.status(200).json({
        success:true,
        product
    })
} catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
        success:false,
        message:error.message
    })
}
```

And per the definition of your schema, your defined the `name, description, price, caterogy, stock` fields as **required** with their individual error messages, which means those **fields cannot be empty** when you call the `.create()` to create a new product else it would trigger a validation error.

Comment: I also have tried this but while using this method I get an other error:                            "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')"

Comment: Try console logging the req.body object to see if you are receiving the required data. Because with this err message it means the name key in the req.body object is undefined.